# How to show Array data which is insert in another table?

Tags: php, php-5.6

I have a problem with the array. I am getting data of row . and insert full row data in another table. but data is not inserting correctly.

```
if (isset($_POST['apply'])){
    $classid=$_POST['class'];
    $section1=$_POST['section'];
    $rowvalue=$db->get_row('fee_chart',array('class'=>$classid,'section'=>$section1));
    //$row=unserialize($rowvalue);
    print_r($rowvalue);

} // in that row data already in the array

Array ( [id] => 1 [class] => 1 [section] => 1 [jan] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [feb] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [mar] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [apr] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [may] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [june] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [july] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [aug] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [sept] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [oct] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [nov] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [decem] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [created_date] => 2019-03-28 06:06:49 [ip_add] => ::1 [timestamp] => 2019-03-28 18:06:49 )
//this is out
```

// now insert this row in new table . output is not showing correctly

```
$allfee=$db->get_row('student_detail',array('id'=>16));
$fee=$allfee['feechart'];

print_r($fee);
// this is output

a:1:{i:0;s:5:"Array";}
```

Comment: How you expect the output to be showing?

Comment: Array ( [id] => 1 [class] => 1 [section] => 1 [jan] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [feb] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [mar] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [apr] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [may] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [june] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [july] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [aug] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [sept] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [oct] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [nov] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [decem] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"100";} [created_date] => 2019-03-28 06:06:49 [ip_add] => ::1 [timestamp] => 2019-03-28 18:06:49 ) this data i want in array

Comment: Well from what you have said I think I can help you (it would be better if you show the saving function and query).

if you are working with data in array's then i have an advice that might help you. usually working with saving arrays is a bit hard due to 'escaping'.

before saving the array into the database you can Serialize() the wole array and save it as a string. and when pulling it out the database use UnSerialize() to get the array back. 

but i dont think thta this is your problem. your issues is with the way you are saving the data